# why is this code snip giving error?

Tags: sockets, android-ndk

```
struct hostent *lphost;
lphost = gethostbyname("server1");
if( lphost NE NULL )
{
   unsigned long ipAddr = inet_addr(lphost->h_addr_list[0]);
}
```

when i do android ndk build of above code snip, i am getting error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" (for line number 5).

Can anybody please let me know why is this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you did not include the header that defines the type `struct hostent` (apparently, the header is `<netdb.h>` http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/netdb.h.html ).

I assume that `NE` is a macro definition resolving back to `!=`.

Comment: if it was header problem, it should give error as undeclared "struct hosten' right?

Comment: @namith: if you declare a pointer towards a struct, no. Only when you dereference the pointer you will get that kind of error. Could you paste the entire program?

Comment: Thanks a lot axeoth, it worked. header was the issue.
Actually i was building it for WINDOWS, LINUX and ANDROID. 
In the include section i had coded like
#if defined(LINUX)
    #include <netdb.h>
#endif
which I replaced with
#if defined(LINUX) || defined(ANDROID)
    #include <netdb.h>
#endif </code>